# having problem in using ng-repeat in another ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-repeat="x in allMessages">
     <div class="card testimonial-card btn-rounded p-1 mb-2">
        <strong>@{{x.sender_username}}</strong>
        <p>{{x.messages}}</p>
        <div ng-repeat="file in x.files">
            {{file}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

From the code above, everything is working well except the second `ng-repeat`. I fetch `allMessages` (which is an array) from the JavaScript which is an array, it also contains another array (files), how can I get the whole content of files displayed per data in the `allMessages`?

Comment: Please add to your question the `allMessages` struct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you code to work properly, your object `allMessages.files` must be an array. `ng-repeat` works only over a collection. This means your `allMessages` object will look like this:

```
[{
    sender_username: "",
    messages: "",
    files: [
        "",
        ""
    ]
}]
```

See working snippet below:

```js
angular.module('testApp', [])
  .controller('TestAppController', function($scope) {
    
    $scope.allMessages = [
      {
        sender_username: "John.Doe",
        messages: "Sample Message",
        files: [
        "file 1",
        "file 2"
        ]
      },
      {
        sender_username: "Janet.Doe",
        messages: "Hi! Whats up?",
        files: [
        "Cinnamon.jpg",
        "Black_tea.png"
        ]
      }
    ];
    
  });
```

```css
.card{
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 10px
}

div.card div{
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


</script>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="TestAppController">
<div ng-repeat="x in allMessages">
     <div class="card testimonial-card btn-rounded p-1 mb-2">
        <strong>@{{x.sender_username}}</strong>
        <p>{{x.messages}}</p>
        <div ng-repeat="file in x.files">
            {{file}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
</body>
```

Comment: Oh, thanks, with this, I've gotten where the source of the problem. When storing the files in mysql, I used serialize, meanwhile, while retrieving it, I used fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC), meaning it fetched the files as mere strings, how can I unserialize only the files column before sending everything(the files column and other columns) to the interface?

Comment: Thanks, I've finally gotten a way t solve the serialize issue, I appreciate, your answer really helped. I am marking yourcontribution as the answer because it works perfectly( if not for my unserialize issue, which was not even included in my question). Anyone with this topic can easily use your contribution as the answer. works well